# Get image by client request in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I try to get a Base64 from a image-URL in my hosted Blazor Webassambly. The URL contains a link to a picture.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url); // there are other methods if you want to get involved with stream processing etc
            var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            return base64String;
        }
```

Throws Exception:

> TypeError: Failed to fetch

The Exception is thrown with any client method.

```
var result = await client.[X](url);
```

Why its impossible to make a request with he http client?

Comment: Can you see the request in your network log? What is the statuscode? Did you check your logging?

Comment: I currently have no logging and have no clue how to track the request. I thought the error message would be common and the problem a known one for blazor or asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with first retrieving the link to the picture and then downloading the bytes from there.

```
string pictureLink = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(await client.GetByteArrayAsync(pictureLink));
```

Comment: With any client method its 'TypeError: Failed to fetch'.